# Duvida sobre implementação de relacionamento N:N utilizando C#

Tags: c#, lista, collection

Estou tendo que fazer um relacionamento entre classes N:N porém armazenando objetos em memória, segue o seguinte relacionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a implementação da seguinte maneira e gostaria de saber se está correto ou não.

> Classe Chemical

```
public class Chemical
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ChemicalName { get; set; }
    public string ChemicalFormula { get; set; }
    public Decimal MW { get; set; }
    public int VFId { get; set; } // Visual_Flow_ID
    public Boolean ProjectChemical { get; set; }

    public Chemical()
    {

    }
```

> Classe Stream

```
    public class Stream
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual IList<StreamComposition> Chemicals { get; set; }

            public Stream()
            {
                this.Chemicals = new List<StreamComposition>();
            }

            public void AddChemical(StreamComposition sc)
            {
                this.Chemicals.Add(sc);

                Console.WriteLine("Adding Chemical: " + sc.Chemical.ChemicalName + 
                    " to the Stream: => " + sc.Stream.Name + "\n");
            }
        }
```

> Classe StreamComposition

```
public class StreamComposition
{
    public virtual Stream Stream { get; set; }

    public virtual Chemical Chemical { get; set; }

    public Decimal MolePerCent { get; set; }

    public StreamComposition()
    {
    }
}
```

**Populando os objetos**

*Criação da Stream*

```
Stream Stream1 = new Stream() { ID = 1, Name = "SHD4", };
```

*Criação dos 3 objetos 'Chemicals'*

```
Chemical ch1 = new Chemical() // Criando uma 'Chemical'
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    ChemicalName = "Hidrogenio",
                    ChemicalFormula = "H",
                    MW = 2,
                    VFId = 2,
                    ProjectChemical = true
                };

Chemical ch2 = new Chemical() // Criando outra 'Chemical'
            {
                ID = 2,
                ChemicalName = "Ferro",
                ChemicalFormula = "Fe",
                MW = 4,
                VFId = 8,
                ProjectChemical = false,
            };

Chemical ch3 = new Chemical()
            {
                ID = 3,
                ChemicalName = "Agua",
                ChemicalFormula = "H20",
                MW = 9,
                VFId = 10,
                ProjectChemical = true,
            };
```

*Criação das 3 classes associativas*

```
StreamComposition sc1 = new StreamComposition() // Criando StreamComposition
            {
                Stream = Stream1,
                Chemical = ch1,
                MolePerCent = 4.0m,
            };

StreamComposition sc2 = new StreamComposition() // Criando StreamComposition
            {
                Stream = Stream1,
                Chemical = ch2,
                MolePerCent = 8.0m,
            };

StreamComposition sc3 = new StreamComposition() // Criando StreamComposition
            {
                Stream = Stream1,
                Chemical = ch3,
                MolePerCent = 8.0m,
            };
```

*Atribuindo as Chemicals criada para a Stream 'Stream1'*

```
            Stream1.AddChemical(sc1);
            Stream1.AddChemical(sc2);
            Stream1.AddChemical(sc3);
```

Comment: O que seria esse Stream em seu domínio? Fiquei em dúvida.

Comment: Stream (Fluxo) no caso é uma classe que irá ter uma lista de Químicas

Comment: Não faltou adicionar na classe *Chemical* a referência pra *StreamComposition*, assim `public virtual IList<StreamComposition> Chemicals { get; set; }`?

Comment: No caso é um exercício acadêmico? Porque o framework já possui classe de Stream, procure por MemoryStream.

Comment: @GabrielColetta acho que nesse caso não é um stream de dados, pelas propriedades da classe, deve ser um fluxo químico

Comment: Talvez a tradução não esteja boa, mas Faltou adicionar as referencias das listas nas Classes Chemical e Stream, como o @RicardoPontual falou